# Would it be O(n 2 *log(n)) or (o)n

Tags: java

Hi guys i tried the notion but dint help what could be the time complexity ?
Please

```
int a = 0;   
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for(k = 0; k < 100000; k++)
            a++;
```

constant multipliers

Comment: FYI, `O(n 2 *log(n))` is not a thing. That would be `O(n log (n))`. Unless that is a typo and you meant `n^2`

Comment: Anyway, what's your reasoning? Why would it be any of those two? And not something else entirely? (*hint hint*)

Comment: OK guys What is the  time complexity for the above code

Comment: The variable `a` is not used.  So optimizer may remove all statements. If so, `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `O(n^2)`.

While you have 3 nested loops, only the outer two loops iterate from 0 to n. The inner most loop iterates from 0 to 100000, and therefore can be considered to take constant time.

In other words, the running time of this code is `100000 * n * n == O(N^2)`.